# Evaluate the orthogonal complement of a rank-1 updated orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $V \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ and $\hat{V} = [V ,a]$. $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. $a \in \mathbb{R}^{r}$. I want to evaluate $\hat{V}^\perp$. Here is my attempt:

$\hat{V}^\perp = Null(\hat{V}^T) $, $Null$ is the nullspace.

$Null(\hat{V}^T) = \{ \nu: [V ,a]^T\nu = 0 \} = \{\nu: V_1^T\nu =0,\dots,V_r^T\nu=0,a^T\nu = 0 \}$, where $V_i$ is the ith column of $V$.

$V_i^T\nu = 0$ if $ \nu = 0 \text{ or } \nu = \sum_{1, j \ne i}^{r-1} \alpha_j V_j$ since $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. $a^T\nu = 0$ if $\nu = 0$ or $ \nu = a^{'}$. where $a'$ is an orthogonal vector to $a$

Now, I am not sure how to write the basis of $Null(\hat{V}^T)$ in a rigorous way?

Comment: An orthogonal matrix is a square matrix, so is $r=m$? From $V_i^T\nu=0$ you conclude that $\nu$ is zero or $\nu=V_j$, why? Note that for example in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ we have $e_1^T (e_2+e_3)=0$. What do you mean by $\nu=a^\perp$, how is $a^\perp$ a vector?

Comment: @Christoph 1. That is correct, I edited the question. 2. Since $V$ is orthogonal, then $V_i^TV_j^T = 0, i \ne j$. I think you mean it can also be a linear combination of $V_j$'s? 3. I mean by $a^\perp$ is orthogonal to $\nu$. I think I should've indicated that $a$ is a vector.

Comment: Of course $a$ is a vector. But $a^\perp$ is *not*. So what should $\nu=a^\perp$ mean?

Comment: @Christoph I think I chose the wrong symbol. I was trying to say $a^\perp$ is a vector orthogonal to $a$. I changed it to $a^{'}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ is orthogonal, $V^T$ is orthogonal as well, in particular of full rank and its null space is trivial, that is $V^\perp = \{0\}$. Augmenting $V$ by an additional vector can only make $V^\perp$ smaller, since in addition to being orthogal to a basis (which is only possible for $\nu=0$) you are adding an additional orthogonality constraint.

In conlusion, $$\hat V^\perp = \underbrace{V^\perp}_{=\{0\}} \cap a^\perp = \{0\}.$$

Comment: but $a$ can be any vector, it does not have to be an orthogonal to all $V_i$'s

Comment: Sure, I never assumed anything about $a$.

Comment: The rank of the augmented matrix $\in R^{r\times r +1}$ is $r$. So the nullspace dimensionality is 1. I do not understand how it could be trivial?

Comment: Here is a counter example: A =  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ It has a nontrivial solution for $Ax = 0$

Comment: @rando The transpose of that matrix has trivial kernel (nullspace)!

Comment: @rando Why did you unaccept the answer? The space $V^\perp$ is the nullspace of $V^T$, not of $V$. Things have to be orthogonal to the columns of $V$, not to the rows.

Comment: That is right. I completely forgot about we are talking about the transpose. Excuse my ignorance :)